# Alternate for LAG function in SQL Server 2005 to calculate growth rate

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, lag, window-functions

How could I create a column with the growth rate of my database?
I have a database and created another table (only with the date and count field) where I have the date and total number of records in it. I would also like to insert another column with the percentage of my growth:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()) AS Date, COUNT(*) AS Count
FROM [Database]
```

My table looks like this:

```
Date        Count        Growth Rate
01/01/18    20.000,00
01/02/18    25.000,00    25,00%
01/03/18    40.000,00    60,00%
```

I use SQL Server 2005, cause this can not use the lag function. How could I do it?

Comment: If you check the MSDN page, LAG wasn't a function until 2012: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017.  The previous way of doing this was using a row number and self joining to the same table ON rowNum = rowNum - 1

Comment: Could you write desired ouptut?

Comment: @StepUp I want to make this calculation from the last row of the 'Count' column to the current one, transform that number into a percentage and put it in the 'Growth Rate' column. 

In case the calculation is this: "(last line - current line) / last line with the lag function it would look something like this: 100 * (count (*) - lag (count (*), 1) / lag (count (*), 1) || '%' as growth  rate

Answer (score 1):

You can use a correlated sub query to emulate LAG function like so:

```
WITH cte (Date, Count) AS (
    SELECT '2018-01-01', 20000.00 UNION
    SELECT '2018-01-02', 25000.00 UNION
    SELECT '2018-01-03', 40000.00
)
SELECT *, (
    SELECT TOP 1 Count
    FROM cte AS x
    WHERE Date < t.Date
    ORDER BY Date DESC
) AS PoorMansLag -- 100 * (Count / PoorMansLag - 1) gives you the result in OP
FROM cte AS t
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possible approach:

```
CREATE TABLE #LagTable (
    [Date] datetime,
    [Count] numeric(10, 2)

)

INSERT INTO #LagTable VALUES ('2018-01-01', 20000.00)
INSERT INTO #LagTable VALUES ('2018-01-02', 25000.00)
INSERT INTO #LagTable VALUES ('2018-01-03', 40000.00);

WITH cte AS (
    SELECT [Date], [Count], ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [Date]) AS RN
    FROM #LagTable
)
SELECT 
    t1.[Date], 
    t1.[Count],
    (t1.[Count] - COALESCE(t2.[Count], 0)) / t2.[Count] * 100 AS GrowthRate
FROM cte t1
LEFT JOIN cte t2 ON (t1.RN = t2.RN + 1)
```

Output:

```
Date                    Count       GrowthRate
2018-01-01 00:00:00.000 20000.00    NULL
2018-02-01 00:00:00.000 25000.00    25.0000000000000
2018-03-01 00:00:00.000 40000.00    60.0000000000000
```